# Unable to run python code in VScode editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylint, vscode-python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bt92.png). I found difficulty in running some python code in VScode editor. I have installed it in windows. There are lots of error such as unused import and pylint(unused-wildcard-import) are shown. Can anyone help me to solve this problem. Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I think the latest Python version that manimlib runs in is Python 3.7 and you are running Python 3.8. That can cause some problems.

(Next time don't post your code as a screenshot, rather paste it and format it so others can copy and test your code :D)